# Apache Zeppelin 0.8.2 docker container login?

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

It appears all the previous version the Apache Zeppelin official docker container automatically log me in as anonymous.  But the latest version, 0.8.2, asks for a login and password.  I have not been able to find any mention of this anywhere.  Has no one attempted to run this container?

This works:  `docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.8.1`

This doesn't:  `docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.8.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic anonymous login works for me:

```
docker run --rm -ti \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -e ZEPPELIN_ADDR=0.0.0.0 \
  --name zeppelin \
  apache/zeppelin:0.8.2
```

Comment: It must be the ZEPPELIN_ADDR part.  I did not have that.  I added it, and now it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the state of it is right now, when I start 0.8.2 I don't get an HTTP response at all. Same command with 0.8.1 works.

Comment: Hi @Michael Ressler, I'm having the same issue. Are you able to run it now?